# How to add strings to array from user input - Java

Tags: java

Is there a way to use `ArrayList()` method to add strings to an array from user input? I have a program that prompts the user to enter a certain input from a JTextBox and I would like to store this input into an array.

I am student, therefore hints and explanations would be preferred over simple answers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend storing the input in a list (such as an `ArrayList`) instead of an array. Arrays have fixed size, while lists typically do not.

Comment: ArrayList is a class. Create a ArrayList and use the add-method. You can get the text from your JTextBox using getText.

Comment: *i would like to store this information in an array.* You first mention that you want the data to be put into an ArrayList, but then you switch to array. Which do you want to use?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496)

Comment: it even explicitly says not to use the self-improvement tag...

Comment: it is available because someone created the tag a long time ago, there is now a site called programmers.se that handles "self-improvement" type questions.  Further this isn't even a self improvement type of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` is a class, not a method.  If you want to put the strings in an array, you need to keep track of

1) The size of the array, or a reasonable upper bound on how many values can be entered.
2) The current index

and you can just put an entered string into the array.

```
String[] strings = new String[SOME_MAX];
...
strings[currentIndex] = userEnteredString;
```

This has the disadvantage that you need to know the size of the array up front.

If you don't, then you can use a `List` implementation.

`List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();`

and then just use the `add` method to add Strings.

To get an array back, you can do

`strings.toArray()`

This obviously has the disadvantage that you only get the array at the end, so it's not acceptable if you need to use an array for the entire process.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to use ArrayList() method to add strings to an array from user input?

The short answer is no.  An array has a fixed number of elements.  The only way you can add more elements is by creating a new array.  This restriction is fundamental to the Java language and the JVM and there are no clever ways around it.

You can use an `ArrayList` as described by Hvgotcodes, but that involves creating a new array.

A more direct way would be to use one of the `Arrays.copyOf(...)` methods to create a new array and then add the extra element; e.g.

```
    String[] bigger = Arrays.copyOf(strings, string.length + 1);
    bigger[bigger.length - 1] = extraString;
```